# End bold text in console but preserve last color

Tags: python

I usually change text color in console by printing ASCII special chars.

For example, to put text in red, just print `\033[0;31m` before it. To make it bold, print `\033[1m`. To go back to defaults, print `\033[0m`.

However, I want to remove bold, but preserve the color, whichever it is.
Is there a simple way to do so ?

Example :

````
This text was previously colored.
Here is an important word I want to put in bold: \033[1m HELLO [special chars to remove bold but preserve previous color] . 
This part is the same color as the beginning ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noted, `\033[0m` will reset *all* formatting.

As per [this source](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797#colors--graphics-mode), `22m` can be seen as the reset sequence for bold text.

So, if you want to just reset the bold, but preserve everything else (including colour), you'll want to use `\033[22m`. That is:

```py
print("\033[31;1mHello\033[22m @fdamien12")
```

[image: Screenshot showing resetting bold output, preserving colour]